# jQuery: Show image on dropdown select makes broken image icon on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I'm using this code to show and hide images depending on dropdown selection:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="my_select" name="select_name" class="order_form_select">
    <option data-img="" value="" disabled selected>Please select&nbsp;↓</option>
    <option data-img="1.jpeg" value="first">First</option>
    <option data-img="2.jpeg" value="second">Second</option>
    <option data-img="3.jpeg" value="third">Third</option>
</select>

<img id="order_form_image" src="">

<script>
document.getElementById("my_select").onchange = showFormatImage;
function showFormatImage() {
    $("#order_form_image").attr('src', $('select[name=select_name] option:selected').attr('data-img'));
    $('#img_src').html($("#order_form_image").attr('src'));
    return false;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It works very good. But on Firefox 48.0.1 I'm getting an broken-image-icon if no dropdown selection. Here's a screenshot:

[image: broken image icon on firefox]

Why that? What can I do to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple and fast solution is to change add this code to your CSS:

```
img[src='']{
    display:none;
}
```

Explanation: As long as there's no image selected in the dropdown, the name of the image is empty. The CSS code hides the whole image tag as long as the images name is empty.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have no source attribute set on load. It only gets set after the change event is triggered.

Hide the element until the src is set and then un-hide.

Comment: How to do that? (I'm not very experienced with Javascript.)

Comment: I found a solution.